# Difference between two regex?

Tags: c, regex

```
^( *)((unsigned *int)|(int)) *[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]* *; *((//)| *)

^ *(unsigned +)?int +[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]* *;( *// *.*)?
```

What the regex is supposed to do is filter for valid int declarations in C, excluding checks for reserved keywords. So far, only the unsigned modifier is supported. What is the difference between the top and the bottom implementation though? Is there a case where the second will not match the first? The first is the reference that is "correct".

If there is a case, let me know. I'd like to try to fix it by myself first.

Comment: You need whitespace after the `int` in any case, and so some of the `*`s are incorrect in the first alternative.  The statement `intA;` passes the first declaration.

Comment: Both will reject valid declarations that contain tabs or comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first will match a string like `unsignedintiforgotaboutspaces;`. The second one does not.

I assume that you did not end your regexes with `$` by design. If not, and your matching engine tries to match the whole string, then the first one will match `int foo; //` (with no space at the end), and the second one does not.

The groups are all different, but this is what Sam already said.

Other than that, I think they should work more or less the same way.

Comment: Not even sure how the first regex could be "correct", given that `intfoo;` won't compile, but `int foo;` obviously does.

Comment: @liori how is it that the second one won't match `int foo; //`?

Answer (score 1):

some differences:

generally speaking, () captures a group when you match your regex(in case you want to know exactly what input matched the parens)

The first one also doesn't require any spaces to actually be in the string.

the symbol: `*` means **0 or more**
the symbol: `+` means **1 or more**